# LIKE %[0-9]% против NOT LIKE %[^0-9]%

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять в чем разница между этими вариантами. Делал тестовое задание

```
В таблице Product найти модели, которые состоят только из цифр
```

Вывод: номер модели, тип модели.

мой запрос вернул правильные значения, но не прошел валидацию

```
Select model, type  from product
where model like '%[0-9]%'
```

Но вот этот запрос работает правильно

```
SELECT model, type
FROM product
WHERE model not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Во втором, мы отрицаем не вхождение символов. Так почему они разнятся, по логике вроде одно и то же.

Comment: Ваш паттерн проверяет, что присутствует хотя бы одна цифра. Правильный - что НЕ присутствует хотя бы одна НЕ цифра. Правильным было бы также, например, `WHERE model REGEXP '^[0-9]*$'`.

Comment: А попробуйте такое условие `WHERE model REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`

Comment: Или `WHERE REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]*$'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё логично:

- `NOT LIKE %[^0-9]%` = *найди все строки, кроме тех, в которых есть хотя бы один символ, отличный от цифры*
- `LIKE %[0-9]%` = *найди все строки, в которых есть хотя бы одна цифра*.

Таким образом, первая команда вернёт только те строки, которые целиком состоят из цифр (если будет хоть одна не-цифра, тест не будет пройден),  тогда как вторая вернёт все строки, в которых имеется хотя бы одна цифра, остальные символы могут быть любыми.

Обратите внимение, `NOT LIKE %[^0-9]%` = `REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`, однако `REGEXP` работает гораздо менее эффективно по сравнению с LIKE.